# Как обновить данные в списке ListView?

Tags: android, java

Данные в ListView передаются из массива

```
String[] items = new String[] {"First", "Second"};

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.items, items));
```

Периодически items меняется, например:

```
items = new String[] {"First", "Second", "Third"};
```

При этом не происходит обновления списка на экране. Как обновить данные в ListView, так чтобы обновление отобразилось на экране?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

пробовал?

Answer (score 1):

Получилось сделать вот так

```
items = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("", ""));
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.items, items);
```

и

```
items.clear();
items.addAll(found);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```